# PL/SQL Developer: variable name syntax highlighting

Tags: syntax-highlighting, plsqldeveloper

Is it possible to highlighting all the variables in the SQL window, starting with a 'l' or 'g'? Our style code commits us to call the names of variables in such a way, for example, local variables are prefixed with 'l', the global 'g', and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible. you can't even do it by writing your own pl/sql developer plugin (you can find a guide and some examples about developing pl/sql developer plugins in the PlugInDoc subfolder inside the installation directory of pl/sql developer).

Even by writing plugins you can only add a set of known keywords: you can't add a syntax highlighting scheme based on prefixes or substrings.

This is the documentation of the only two calls made available for plugin developers for influencing syntax highlighting:

```
 ---IDE_SetCustomKeywords : Available in version 300
      C++     void IDE_SetCustomKeywords(char *Keywords) 
      Delphi  procedure IDE_SetCustomKeywords(Keywords: PChar) 
 Fills the custom keywords with the words in the Keywords parameter. 
 Words should be separated by cr/lf. 
 The currently used keywords will be overwritten. 


 --- IDE_SetKeywords : Available in version 300
     C++     void IDE_SetKeywords(int ID, int Style, char *Keywords) 
     Delphi  procedure IDE_SetKeywords(ID, Style: Integer; Keywords: PChar) 

 Adds a number of keywords with a specific style. 
 This function is more specific then IDE_SetCustomKeywords because 
 this one can set multiple sets of keywords for different highlighting styles.
 ID should be the PlugIn ID as returned by the IdentifyPlugIn function. 
 Style can be one of the following values: 
 10: Custom 
 11: Keywords
```